# How to add style to a php snippet

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my wordpress site I have

```
<?php wp_loginout(); ?>
```

which produces

```
<a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php">Log in</a>
```

I want to add the following style to the a tag

```
style="color:white;"
```

I don't know php. Would I try find the php and then add it somehow? And how would I add it to the php?

Comment: you can use external style css   for example :  .abc a { color:white; }

Comment: I don't see a class tag

Comment: please share link here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
<div id='anchorStyle'>   <!-- define div  -->
  <?php wp_loginout(); ?> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
#anchorStyle a{
  color:white;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

wp_loginout() has a filter hook 'loginout' which you could use to influence the output.
Add a filter function to functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('loginout', 'loginout_selector');
function loginout_selector($text) {
$selector = 'class="woo-sc-button"';
$text = str_replace('<a ', '<a '.$selector, $text);
return $text;
}
```

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php replace/add this filter

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_secondary_items','wpsites_loginout_menu_link' );

function wpsites_loginout_menu_link( $menu ) {
    $loginout = '<li class="myNewClass">' . wp_loginout($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], false ) . '</li>';
    $menu .= $loginout;
    return $menu;
}
```

fore reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout

Answer (score 0):

you can't style the php. The **a** tag is the tag you should style (html).

if you want to add your style to the **a** tag best practice is to find/create the file which has extension .css or create a file called (name).css

Simple way to style all your a tags is

```
a {

color: white;

}
```

Again, this styles all **a** tags and I don't know the entire code.

If you would want to specify which **a** tag gets which colors. Read up on CSS and adding class/id or nested elements.